# CSS - aligning H1 with a span symbol

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm styling the section headings for a website and I can't quite get a span symbol and a H1 heading to align properly. This is how it looks on the site -

[image: heading]

Annoyingly, when I've come to include the code in this snippet the two elements seem to align. When I check the console the span element seems to have a buffer around the symbol which prompts it slightly out of line as you can see in the image. I'm using bootstrap for the site, could this be a hidden rule that I'm missing?

```css
.secthead span {

  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium', sans-serif;
}

.secthead h1 {
 
  font-size: 50px;
 font-family: 'Gotham-Medium', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
  
}

.secthead h1, span {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="secthead"><span style="color: rgb(255,128,55);">&#43;</span><h1>Who We Are</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `vertical-align: middle;` in both tag & remove padding from bottom in `h1` tag. check updated snippet below..

```css
.secthead span {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium', sans-serif;
}

.secthead h1 {     
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 0px 20px;      
}

.secthead h1, span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="secthead"><span style="color: rgb(255,128,55);">&#43;</span><h1>Who We Are</h1></div>
```

Comment: Just adding to this that OP might want to use `.secthead h1, .secthead span` instead of `.secthead h1, span`, thus not applying the style to all spans.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a height and line-height.

```css
.secthead span {

  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium', sans-serif;
}

.secthead h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
  line-height: 92px;
  
  
}

.secthead h1, .secthead span {
  height: 92px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height: 92px;
}
```

```html
<div class="secthead">
  <span style="color: rgb(255,128,55);">&#43;</span>
  <h1>Who We Are</h1>
</div>
```